# Parsing for text in table not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the following text in the tags.

```
<td align="center" valign="top">I AM TRYING TO GET THIS</td>
```

this is in a table, and this specific text is a specific row and column, I am trying to get this along with the rest of the column.

I have tried the for loops, and I tried this as well:

```
r = driver.get("url")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

regex = '<td align="center" valign="top">(.+?)</td>'

pattern = re.compile(regex)

grade = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print(grade)
```

I would prefer BS4 way to do it.

Comment: `requests` is not for HTML parsing but for sending data.

Comment: BeautifulSoup: `for x in soup.find_all('td'): print(x.text.strip())`

Comment: htmltext = htmlfile.read()? where did this htmlfile came from? maybe it's r.read()

Answer (score 1):

I can't check it but it should work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for x in soup.find_all('td'): 
    print(x.text.strip())
```

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: It means you did't find element on page but you use `text` - so you try to do `None.text`

Comment: But the element is there? can you edit your answer to fix this? do you know how?

Comment: Is it possible to use the xpath? and then print the results of the xpath? It is not working for me.

Comment: You can use xpath if you use `lxml` instead of `BS` but it change nothing if there are no elements on page or elements are added by JavaScript (BS doesn't run JavaScript) - so you have to find out why you can't get result.

Comment: If it is javascript how do i go about it?

Comment: then you can use `Selenium` which opens page in browser and lets you control this browser and get data from browser after it loads page and runs JavaScript. Or - JavaScript mostly display data which it downloads from server so you can manually find url used by JavaScript to download data and then use it with `requests`. You can use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see communication between browser and server and find url uses by JavaScript. (it needs more work than Selenium but later script can be faster).